# UDP send task waiting for messages in the queue will drain CPU

Tags: c#, udp, queue

I'm doing an udp sender routine that waits for messages in a queue and then sends them to all configured listener ports (code is simplified here).

To do that i've created an UDPClient working on a queue inside a task.

I've put code in a WHILE TRUE using a cancellation token to exit, and on each roundtrip i'm checking if queue contains something, else next loop...

This is REALLY cpu consuming. I was able to reduce it adding a Thread.Sleep on each cycle, but this will slow up the process when i need to send multiple packets on a short time and they arrive not at the same millisecond.

Is there a method to stay watching for elements in queue raises that will stay inside the loop cycle without continuously running on it?

```
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                using (var udpClient = new UdpClient(AddressFamily.InterNetwork))
                {
                    udpClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
                    while (true)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(100); //This will save 30% CPU
                        while (UdpOutboundMessageQueue.Count > 0)
                        {
                            if (UdpOutboundMessageQueue.TryDequeue(out Tuple<NetworkOutboundMessageTypeEnum, string> dequeueResult))
                            {
                                byte[] byteMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dequeueResult.Item2);
                                await udpClient.SendAsync(byteMessage, byteMessage.Length, dequeueResult.Item1);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: See the MSDN ASYNC Socket examples to see how to properly block waiting for a response : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/socket-code-examples

Comment: I'm not waiting for a receiving message, I'm waiting for an empty queue...

Comment: Than what is the Sleep doing?  Are you send data at 100mbs the Ethernet rate?  Than why are you waiting.  You have no control with Ethernet to guarantee the arrival time between messages.

Comment: The function is waiting for something to be sent. It basically opens a UDPClient without defined target address, and when something arrives on the queue it will get the endpoint for the message and sends it. To do that it will monitor the queue for incoming messages, but i don't know how to wait on the queue for new messages without cycle... if it's possible... otherwise i will probably work on the queue add element event to trigger it...

Comment: See the MSDN  samples.  The samples use : ManualResetEvent connectDone =   
        new ManualResetEvent(false);

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object of the SemaphoreSlim class which has a WaitAsync method that you can use in async code.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=net-5.0

Or you can use the TPL NuGet package that has a BufferBlock class, which can be used to wait until a buffer is queued.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl